# How to get individual cell in table using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a table:

```
      -60   -40   -20     0    20    40    60
100   520   440   380   320   280   240   210
110   600   500   430   370   320   280   250
120   670   570   490   420   370   330   290
130   740   630   550   480   420   370   330
140   810   690   600   530   470   410   370
```

The headers along the top are a wind vector and the first col on the left is a distance. The actual data in the 'body' of the table is just a fuel additive.

I am very new to Pandas and Numpy so please excuse the simplicity of the question. What I would like to know is, how can I enter the table using the headers to retrieve one number? I have seen its possible using indexes, but I don't want to use that method if I don't have to.

for example:
I have a wind unit of `-60` and a distance of `120` so I need to retrieve the number `670`. How can I use Numpy or Pandas to do this?

Also, if I have a wind unit of say `-50` and a distance of `125`, is it then possible to interpolate these in a simple way?

EDIT:

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('fuel_adjustment.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=0,index_col=0)

print(df.loc[120, -60])
```

But get the error:

```
line 3083, in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: -60
```

Comment: Assuming indices are integers: `df.loc[120,-60]` would yield `670`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select any cell from existing indices using:

```
df.loc[120,-60]
```

The type of the indices needs however to be integer. If not, you can fix it using:

```
df.index = df.index.map(int)
df.columns = df.columns.map(int)
```

For interpolation, you need to add the empty new rows/columns using `reindex`, then apply [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) on each dimension.

```
(df.reindex(index=sorted(df.index.to_list()+[125]),
           columns=sorted(df. columns.to_list()+[-50]))
   .interpolate(axis=1, method='index')
   .interpolate(method='index')
)
```

Output:

```
       -60    -50    -40    -20     0      20     40     60
100  520.0  480.0  440.0  380.0  320.0  280.0  240.0  210.0
110  600.0  550.0  500.0  430.0  370.0  320.0  280.0  250.0
120  670.0  620.0  570.0  490.0  420.0  370.0  330.0  290.0
125  705.0  652.5  600.0  520.0  450.0  395.0  350.0  310.0
130  740.0  685.0  630.0  550.0  480.0  420.0  370.0  330.0
140  810.0  750.0  690.0  600.0  530.0  470.0  410.0  370.0
```

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use df.loc for that purpose

```
df.loc[120,-60]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have now tried this and have an error, please see my edited question.

Comment: @PW1990 what is the type of your indexes? Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70502578/16343464) for a conversion to int.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the data type of index and column. That should be the reason why you failed `df.loc[120,-60]`.

Try:

```
df.loc[120, "-60"]
```

To validate the data type, you may call:

```
>>> df.index
Int64Index([100, 110, 120, 130, 140], dtype='int64')
>>> df.columns
Index(['-60', '-40', '-20', '0', '20', '40', '60'], dtype='object')
```

If you want to turn the header of columns into int64, you may need to turn it into numeric:

```
df.columns = pd.to_numeric(df.columns)
```

---

For interpolation, I think the only way would be creating that nonexistent index and column first, then you can get that value. However, it will grow your df rapidly if it's frequently query.

1. First, you need to add the nonexistent index and column.
2. Interpolate row-wise and column-wise.
3. Get your value.

```
new_index = df.index.to_list()
new_index.append(125)
new_index.sort()

new_col = df.columns.to_list()
new_col.append(-50)
new_col.sort()

df = df.reindex(index=new_index, columns=new_col)
df = df.interpolate(axis=1).interpolate()
print(df[125, -50])
```

Another way is to write a function to fetch relative numbers and returns the interpolate result.

1. Find the upper and lower indexes and columns of your target.
2. Fetch the four numbers.
3. Sequentially interpolate the index and column.

Comment: Thank you Max, this is excellent. I am thinking, as there will be many combinations of interpolations that probably the best be is to do what you suggested and do it manually instead of adding rows each time.

Comment: Make sure to chose the interpolation method, otherwise you'll just get the mean of the values ;)